# Entity Framework map using Foreign Key and type field

Tags: entity-framework

This is a simplified version of the problem I'm facing.  Basically, I have an existing database with code-first Entity Framework on top of, and there are several tables where I see an ObjectId and ObjectType field.  Depending on the ObjectType, the table can be joined to one of several other disparate tables which do not share a hierarchy.

For example, given the following database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE BarCode
(
Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ObjectType int NOT NULL,
ObjectId int NOT NULL,
BarCodeValue varchar(20) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE Person
(
Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar(20),
)

CREATE TABLE Package
(
Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar(20),
)
```

I might see rows in the BarCode table with an ObjectType of 1, which correspond to Person records, or rows with an ObjectType of 2, which correspond to Package records.

In Entity Framework, how do I set up a mapping so that the Person entity can have a BarCode and the Package entity can have a Barcode?  I don't see where the Map() method allows you to specify any fields other than the foreign key field.  Like I said, there's really no hierarchy among these objects, it's more that they share a common attribute.  Sort of like decorating a class with an interface vs. having it inherit from something.

Comment: `Code First` is more like the bottom of the database. I'm writing that because, if `Code First` workflow is used, then somewhere in your code you have entities that mirror the tables in your database. I think that rather than showing the SQL code for creating the tables it would be much better to find the `BarCode`, `Person` and `Package` entities in your solution and show them in the post.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify the approach.  This is a legacy database structure, and we are updating the EDMX off of the database, but we are using code first to manually code the entities, entity mappings, and includes ourselves using T4 templates, for several reasons (circular dependencies, large object graphs crossing service boundaries, etc.).  I don't have control over the architecture of this system, I'm merely trying to solve a problem caused by the legacy database structure.